# How to compare data from two different tables SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

This maybe simple but I'm not sure how to go about it.
I have 2 tables Match and Players

```
Players table
-------------
PlayerID     int
PlayerName   varchar(20)
TeamID       int
TeamName     varchar(10)

Match table
-----------
MatchID         int 
Team1           varchar(20)
Team2           varchar(20)
MatchDate       date
```

For example for a specific match I would like to list all player names from both teams.

Say `28/03/16 Liverpool vs Arsenal`, how do I get the player names from the Players table?

Anything you could tell me will help.

Comment: Formatted post. Question is still very low quality, OP should edit with attempts and more details about the existing queries tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing team names as team1 and team2 in your match table, store their corresponding team ids.

Edit : Every match should unique match id, so that date filter is not required.

This could help you to retrieve records using the query :

```
select * from players a where exists(select 1 from match b where 
b.MATCH_ID= :match_id and (a.team_id=b.team1 OR
a.team_id =b.team2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the row from `match` table. If you don't know if team1 is Liverpool or Arsenal, or vice versa for team2

```
 SELECT m.matchid
   FROM match m
  WHERE m.date = TO_DATE('2016-03-28','YYYY-MM-DD')
    AND m.team1 IN ('Liverpool','Arsenal')
    AND m.team2 IN ('Liverpool','Arsenal')
    AND m.team1 <> m.team2
```

Next, make two copies of the row...

```
 SELECT m.matchid
   FROM (SELECT 1 AS i UNION ALL SELECT 2) d
  CROSS
   JOIN match m
  WHERE m.date = TO_DATE('2016-03-28','YYYY-MM-DD')
    AND m.team1 IN ('Liverpool','Arsenal')
    AND m.team2 IN ('Liverpool','Arsenal')
    AND m.team1 <> m.team2
```

The perform join to the players table, looks like we use teamname column to match.

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN d.i = 1 THEN m.team1 ELSE m.team2 END AS teamname
      , p.playername
   FROM (SELECT 1 AS i UNION ALL SELECT 2) d
   JOIN match m
     ON m.date = TO_DATE('2016-03-28','YYYY-MM-DD')
    AND m.team1 IN ('Liverpool','Arsenal')
    AND m.team2 IN ('Liverpool','Arsenal')
    AND m.team1 <> m.team2
   LEFT
   JOIN players p
     ON p.teamname IN (m.team1, m.team2) 
  ORDER BY d.i, p.playerid
```

Comment: If you only want a list of players, without which team they are on, eliminate the first expression in the SELECT list that returns teamname. You can also remove the LEFT keyword to make it an inner join. But that would only make a difference if both teams had no players.)